# pix 501 encryption license reduces inside hosts to 10

Tags: cisco, encryption, cisco-pix, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have an unlimted pix 501 with no encryption license installed.  I have applied for and received a 3DES license.  When I install the 3DES license, the inside hosts goes from unlimited to 10.  Thankfully I had the presence of mind to keep a note of the old activation key.

Is this normal behaviour?

I would have thought not as I bought the pix as unlimited.

Thanks

Cammy

Answer (score 1):

That's not been my experience with PIXen.  I've added 3DES to a couple of them that were unlimited before, and they stayed that way, however they were slightly larger units.  Yours still sounds abnormal to me.  As if the new key is 3DES restricted instead of 3DES unlimited.

Comment: Yes.  That's what is happening.  I read another post on tektips where the same thing had happened to someone and they had to raise a TAC case to get cisco to solve it.  Unfortunately, We don't have cisco support.

Comment: You should be able to get TAC support on licensing issues without a contract.  You just can't get free software updates and actual configuration support.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different types of licenses.

You probably bought the cheapest license and therefore got a restricted license.

If you want an unrestricted license for the 501, they sell them, but of course, they will be more expensive.

The reseller you purchased the license from should have explained this BEFORE they sold you the license.  Did you talk with someone? A sales person? A tech?

For the PIX 501, I'm pretty sure there are 10-users, 50-users, and unlimited.

HTH
Keith

Comment: Hi

I am aware of the different types of licenses available for the pix 501.  The one we have is UL but after applying the encryption activation-key supplied by cisco, it changes to a 10 user license.  I am currently in contact with cisco licensing to resolve it.